# How to decrypt a base64 string

Tags: encryption, base64

I have a "black box" program that can encrypt a given integer to a base64 string. I can input any integer and get an output. i.e.:

```
919771840    Nva4owsaPYFWJJQFpB+phQ==       
919771850    D85pAYyVp7jBtw9yxW9YBQ==       
919771860    clMLImNuPb47Xs5ZpHtixA==       
919771870    JuUHKtvHWDx+Re8uVjGTiw==       
919771880   bUh0gcJBxKUevTZ8xdLwiQ==        
919771890    fEw9ATjAavzQed/6j3Emlw==       
919771900    9/5yxmhaW99QmussBkr35Q==       
919771910    t2XaLKggSC5lKxLGQSdhEQ==       
919771920    cddK8g7ecsYCjHoL7iN1CA==       
919771930    zubr6JlanKPYTYx3Un/GeQ==       
919771940   Y3nfRH0R7RGNDi9OkhKZFw==        
919771950   jObfRgOh+GgGcXQQrQeMqw==        
919771960   KYBsPfMrqFq9peCbsZIcQA==        
919771970   1agEgLiI7NDQItH4kkiDTw==        
919771980   jscdgP6xOi59mr0LKwA0IQ==        
919771990   KVjuZM661bDX4fPcBRMNDg==
```

Is there any way that I can decrypt a base64 string (i.e. `Kr9ritjAjkHS9dVid262bw==`) back to an integer? I have no idea how it is encrypted (key or method used) since it is in a black box program. I cannot run it with all the possible integer input. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, because ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. This question doesn't have any value for future readers and we're not here to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/).

Comment: You need to first determine the encryption algorithm.  Also, you need to figure out the base64 input char decoding.  Using an online decoder, none of those decode to UTF-8 strings, but a few other decoder possibilities work.  So in summary, your first task is to start reverse engineering!

Comment: w/ knowing the algorithm used, is it possible to reverse engineering the key out? I know for a fact that for a 10 digits integer, the first 11 char is the same as long as the first 8 digits are the same:
2010738350  GG1uBFApLVXhsBuTd3NZGQ==
2010738351  GG1uBFApLVXbdtVZRLrNTg==
2010738352  GG1uBFApLVX+4IzprPS9bQ==
2010738353  GG1uBFApLVUJI2NsZPMtuA==
2010738354  GG1uBFApLVXrG8Zo7XwCVw==
2010738355  GG1uBFApLVXdkKxQ33Bk0A==
2010738356  GG1uBFApLVXhxK7n28RKRQ==
2010738357  GG1uBFApLVWf3mKUadUkSQ==
2010738358  GG1uBFApLVUnubxBiBgBCg==
2010738359  GG1uBFApLVWKE0pYXKIaDA==

Comment: Maybe you can, maybe you don't. Either way, this is not a good question for Stack Overflow. The new data that you posted suggests that this is not very secure encryption.

Comment: And for less then 8 digits integer, the encrypted string is 12 bytes: 
1325994  L2N3Fv/19Aw=
1325995  ZP+nZEgPwGw=
1325996  VKTG/28p87Q=
By the way, why this is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Is this against any rule?

Comment: If you are going to try the route of reverse engineering and the program is truly a black box, finding the key should be relatively easy. It must be distributed with the program, either as a string in source code or a file in an executable archive (such as a JAR file). Using a decompilation or string dumping tool (depending on what type of executable it is) should give you the key much more easily than known text attacks

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is not encryption but encoding. There is no key, and only one possible output for every input. It is fully reversible and almost every language has a common library that will encode and decode base64 strings for you.

**Edit**

If you mean that the program is using some true encryption algorithm to encrypt the integer to binary data and then base64 encoding that binary data, then the answer is that you cannot retrieve the original integer. It just can't be done without knowing the algorithm used, let alone the key.

Comment: OP talks only about Base64, but this question is not about the Base64, but rather the encryption of integers. As you can see the example "encodings" differ by more than 4 bytes despite only changing a single digit in the plaintext.

Comment: Added a section to address your interpretation of the question

Comment: yes. I meant to decrypt the decoded base64 string. That is why I used the term decrypt instead of decode.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using python then it can be decoded as follow.

```
import base64
encoded = base64.b64encode('data to be encoded')
data = base64.b64decode(encoded)
```

Comment: It's not the encoding that's the problem here, but rather the encryption.